# Unable to update user policy via VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

One Domain user with laptop is gone abroad. I had change some user policy for that Domain User. I have connected his laptop via internet through VPN to my Local Network.

I am getting the following error, when i am trying to update the policy, however i am able to successfully update the computer policy ( please see the print-screen )

" The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the user name.
This could be caused by one of more of the following:
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller.
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain co
ntroller has not replicated to the current domain controller).

To diagnose the failure, review the event log or run GPRESULT /H GPReport.html f
rom the command line to access information about Group Policy results. "
[image]

I have checked through nslookup, i am successfully able to resolve my domain name. I have also added my FQDN in host file in his laptop. I can successfully ping my DC via ip address and via FQDN.

I have also checked that his Username is getting resolve via Security permission on folder ( ACL )

Please let me know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same problem.
If you are using VPN over Data Card Connection.
than please check whether you are able to access share folder of Domain ( eg corp.abc.com )

Go to Start > run > \corp.abc.com

If you are not able to open Sysvol folder. than please open command prompt.

Net Use \\corp.qualitykiosk.com\sysvol Password /user:corp\Username

Answer (score 1):

Enable Group Policy verbose logging on the client:

https://blogs.technet.com/b/mempson/archive/2010/01/10/userenvlog-for-windows-vista-2008-win7.aspx

(Restart may be required).

Run `gpupdate /force` from a non-elevated command prompt (for user-mode only update).

There should be detailed information recorded in %systemroot%\debug\usermode\gpsvc.log

At the beginning of the update, there should be information similar to the following:

```
GPSVC(348.35c) 07:52:04:964 Server_ProcessRefresh:: bMachine = 0, SID = null, bForceRefresh = 1, bRefreshAllUsers = 0, dwTimeout = 600000
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:978 GPOThread: Background forced refresh requested, calling GetUserNameEx to refresh DN cache which returned 0x0
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:979 NlaQueryNetSignatures returned 1 networks
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:979 Found a intranet+auth network
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:980 # of interfaces : 1
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:980 Interface ID: {62997312-4017-48FE-B662-73CEBF98BFD7}
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:980 Compartment ID: 1
GPSVC(348.bfc) 07:52:04:980 Setting the CompartmentId [1] on the current thread
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:197 GPOThread: Background forced refresh requested, calling GetUserNameEx to refresh DN cache which returned 0x0
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:207 GPLockPolicySection: Sid = (null), dwTimeout = 30000, dwFlags = 65538
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:207 LockPolicySection called for user <Machine>
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:208 Sync Lock Called
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:208 Reader Lock got immediately. m_cReadersInLock : 1
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:208 Lock taken successfully
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:208 UnLockPolicySection called for user <Machine>
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:209 Found the caller in the ReaderHavingLock List. Removing it...
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:209 Setting lock state as notLocked
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:209 UnLocked successfully
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:212 GetDomainControllerConnectionInfo: Enabling bandwidth estimate.
GPSVC(348.e24) 07:52:05:715 Started bandwidth estimation successfully
```